# Cast to Projector(s) with no Internet

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, raspberry-pi, miracast

I run tournament events in sports halls and have projector(s) running showing information. Currently this works via a local WiFi network I have set up with the router (that I have modded to be able to have local DNS) connected to my windows laptop and raspberry pi's connected to that and plugged into the projectors. They show a single webpage that is set to auto-refresh.

This works well but it is a bit involved and I need an easier solution for when I'm not there. We can never rely on internet connection so it's basically an internal WiFi network.

I am wondering if this would be possible using casting technology  like miracast or chromecasts but I can't tell if internet would still be needed or if I can cast to multiple devices?

Comment: Miracast requires an compatible Wireless adapter, and likely DNS/DHCP, doubt Miracast would work in the configuration you describe

Comment: In my experience Miracast can be hopelessly unreliable. I'd stay away from it.

Comment: OK that sounds like miracast is out. Any other options you can think of?

Comment: What's wrong with the current setup? Configure Pis to auto-connect to WiFi and launch all necessary software on boot, then instruct someone to simply plug everything in and wait a minute for Pis to boot.

Comment: Because sometimes things go wrong and can't connect for various reasons. Usually a restart works or a VNC in but when I'm not there, there is no tech experience and would prefer a simpler setup

Comment: How about a script that automatically runs "shutdown -r now"?  Does apache or etc function?  If no, automatically restart apache.  If that fails shutdown -r now.  Many possibilities exist, in terms of scripts that automatically monitor and restart things on an as needed basis.